# Using multiple Topic names with azure

Tags: azure

How can I create multiple Topic clients in a single class?

If I autowire topic client and it takes topic name from application.properties. but how can I use multiple topics & multiple subscriptions.

Any Hints?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate on your question?

With a limited understanding of your question, all I can say is - 
You can create any number of topic clients in a single class. Each topic client can talk to only one topic.

If you want to read multiple topic names from application.properties, you could pass a list of names in a CSV format (comma separated values) and then split it in your code.

If none of the above answers your question, it would be great if you could provide a sample snippet of how you are instantiating your topic client right now.